# How to get month name to show up in Loop return

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I am learning JS and am having trouble figuring this out. I would like to ask if any of you can spot my error on why my loop results are coming out as "undefined" instead of "december" 12 times. Please help!

Thanks

```
window.onload = function() {
document.getElementById("months").innerHTML = getMonth(12);   
};

for(var month=0; month < 12; month++)
{

document.getElementById("months").innerHTML = document.getElementById("months").innerHTML + "<br/>" + month + getMonth(month); 
}

function getMonth(month) {
    var monthName;
    if (month == 12) {
        monthName = "December";
    }
    return monthName;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/priswiz/KufcA/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your method returns `December` only when its param is equal to 12, yet `month` variable only gets to 12 when loop is broken (honoring the `month < 12` condition). Tweaking your method with...

```
if (month == **11**) {
```

... will give you December right at the end of this list.

Having said all that, I'd strongly recommend using an established library (such as [**Moment.js**](http://momentjs.com/)) to work with dates. It'll save you a LOT of time and nerves. )

As a sidenote, I'd have built the whole 'monthes-string' first, only then use it as `innerHTML`. DOM operations are to be used sparingly.

Comment: Hi thank you, I am getting December as a result now, but how can I have it repeat 12 times?

Comment: For all the months? Just remove the check (`if (month == 11)` line) then.

Comment: If I wanted to repeat December 12 times?

Comment: Then your function (which is called 12 times) should always return string `'December'`, right? That's what I meant by 'remove the check'. But, frankly speaking, I'm starting to lose your case a bit: it's not necessary to make a special function that returns the same value all the time - simple variable would suffice here.

Comment: Sorry for all the questions, I'm just trying to learn, maybe not a real case scenario but I just want to understand it. Thank you for all your help :)

Answer (score 1):

December is month number 11. it starts at 0

Answer (score 1):

`month` is being incremented from `0` to `11` (it stops before reaching `12`). Since the value of `month` passed to `getMonth` is never `12`, the returned `monthName` is always undefined.

What you want instead is a way of mapping the month digit to a name. For example:

```
function getMonth(month) {
    var monthStr = ['January', 'February', ... ];
    return monthStr[month];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated your jsfiddle... basically :

```
for(var month=1; month < 13; month++)
```

to haves months from 1 to 12

and

```
var monthName="";
```

to avoid "undefined"